# Cant install Bower on pi with python No compatible version found: bower

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, bower, polymer-designer-tool

Newbie here.

I have spent hours. Goal is to install Poylmer, I tried installing bower to no end. Then did Poylmer zip file and put it in myproject directory.

I am trying to do 10 min tutorial LOL it requires bower which I have not been success full. Node, npm and Git showed good installs. Ran updates. Rebooted. Tried installs again.

Then checked node version

```
  pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install node
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
node is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

Still get this:

```
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install bower
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bower
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo npm install -g bower
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bower
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/bower

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: bower
npm ERR! No valid targets found.
npm ERR! Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:415:44)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:408:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:147:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs.js:230:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/pi/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.18.7-v7+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message No compatible version found: bower
npm ERR! message No valid targets found.
npm ERR! message Perhaps not compatible with your version of node?
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

I have a deadline approaching fast. All help is much appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: You're running quite an old version of Node, tried updating it as the message suggests?

Comment: I thought I did that in the first block of code, it says "node is already the newest version" ? Did I do something wrong there?

Comment: Yup, you need to enter the commands mentioned here - http://elinux.org/Node.js_on_RPi#Download_the_most_recent_arm_version_of_Node.js

Comment: Fixed it, I needed to update npm. I had to use npm to update npm.

Answer (score -1):

Installing `Bower` using `npm` worked for me. `apt-get install` of `Bower` won't work.

Try the following command: `sudo npm install -g bower`